# Bottle request.files.getall() returns empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, crud, bottle

I got problem with batch image upload using bottle. The request.files.getall() returns empty list, even though I am selecting and uploading files.

My form looks as follows:

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gallery">Select images:</label>
        <input id="gallery" type="file" name="gallery" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png" multiple>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
@route('/upload', method='POST')
def newGallery():
    name = request.forms.get('name')
    pictures = request.files.getall('gallery')

    for picture in pictures:
        print(picture.filename)

    return template('new.html')
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: show your `new.html`

Comment: here it is : https://pastebin.com/3pw86VK1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forms.getall(*)` worked

*.py file

```
@bottle.get('/go')
def go():
    return bottle.template('new.html')

@bottle.post('/go')
def goo():
    name = bottle.request.forms.get('email')
    pictures = bottle.request.forms.getall('gallery')
    for picture in pictures:
        print(picture)
    return bottle.template(' hi {{name}}, {{picture}} ', name=name, picture=picture)
```

Also, changed `form` tag in `new.html` to

```
    <form method="post">
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. Any idea why request.files('*') didn't work?

Comment: And actually the problem now is that I got the file names, but I don't have the files that I want to upload to the server. So how do I save the file now?

I would say that "picture.save(path,overwrite=True)" is not working, since picture is just string in this solution.

Thanks for help.